# Apply operation to only a subset of columns in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm calculating the z-score of columns which are float32, and I do it like this:

This is my dataframe:

```
data.head()
index   a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h       i   j   k
0      39   6   13  4   0   1   4   2174    0   40  38
1      50   5   13  2   3   0   4   0       0   13  38
```

I want to calculate z-score only for colums which are float32. (a, c, h, i, j)

```
cols = list(data.columns[data.dtypes == 'float32'])
_means = np.mean(data[cols], axis=0)
_stds = np.std(data[cols], axis=0)
```

I need to apply this operation to cols only while preserve the value of _means and _stds:

```
(data - self._means) / self._stds
```

If I tried the above I get NaN for columns which are not cols.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Select float with `df2 = df.select_dtypes('float32')`, then `(df2 - df2.mean()) / df2.std()`

Comment: what is the cleanest way to merge the new df2 with other non-float32 columns in df?

Comment: `result = pd.concat([df, new_df2], axis=1)`?